# Checkstyle : Why as a developer we should worry about it?

Tags: java, coding-style, checkstyle, pmd

I am not sure whether it is right forum or not.

I just want to ask, what is there in checkstyle for developer. 
PMD is useful because it improve our coding skills but checkstyle I am not sure. Some checkstyle warning are too restrict like you can have only 1 capital letter in variable name, import and variable declaration should be alphabetically ordered etc.

I like checkstyle until it is just a save action, but not if I manually need to change our working code.

What is your opinion about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkstyle is flexible. You can turn off or tweak its rules. The point is to help a team of developers standardize on certain coding conventions so that you are not constantly reformatting each others' code or debating endlessly over little details. It means all code in the code base looks the same and that consistency typically makes it easier for people to pick things up.

Answer (score 2):

Checkstyle is a programmers answer to re-reading one's own code to check for improvements. A program is written to do it instead.

Checkstyle allows certain warnings to be turned on or off, and the warnings should just be taken as a reminder to spend some extra time thinking about the way of implementation in some cases. It should be tuned to the programmers preference inho.

More importantly though. For readability's sake, it can be good to have an agreed upon coding style when working on a project together with other people. Which checkstyle could help enforce, by loading certain agreed upon settings into it.

Answer (score 0):

I use IntelliJ which has quick fixes for a lot of it's inspections, it doesn't just find problem but helps you fix them which is much better IMHO.

You need to focus on the important issues like; does my program do what the user needs, not sorting imports.

In short, you should consider whether this tools is helping you improve your delivery or is it distracting you.

Comment: Thanks Peter..I am totally agree with you, we should focus more on function and performance more than style of code.

Comment: if i (WrOTe My) { resPonse LIKE } this, you'd probably ((find) it HARDER) TO Read than if I adopted a more conventional style. That's the kind of issue that Checkstyle helps solve in a team.

Comment: @aetheria if someone did that I would have a very short and to the point talk with them to let them know what is expected. +1